# JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

Im trying to get my form to validate...so basically its working, but a little bit too well, I have two text boxes, one is a start date, the other an end date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy

if the start date is greater than the end date...there is an error
if the end date is less than the start date...there is an error
if the start date is less than today's date...there is an error

The only thing is when I correct the error, the error warning is still there...here is my code:

```
    dates.change(function () {
        var testDate = $(this).val();
        var otherDate = dates.not(this).val();
        var now = new Date();
        now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Pass Dates
        if (testDate != '' && new Date(testDate) < now) {
            addError($(this));
            $('.flightDateError').text('* Dates cannot be earlier than today.');
            isValid = false;
            return;
        }

        // Required Text 
        if ($(this).hasClass("FromCal") && testDate == '') {
            addError($(this));
            $('.flightDateError').text('* Required');
            isValid = false;
            return;
        }
        // Validate Date
        if (!isValidDate(testDate)) {
            // $(this).addClass('validation_error_input');  
            addError($(this));
            $('.flightDateError').text('* Invalid Date');
            isValid = false;
            return;
        }
        else {
            // $(this).removeClass('validation_error_input');
            removeError($(this));
            if (!dates.not(this).hasClass('validation_error_input'))
                $('.flightDateError').text(' ');
        }

        // Validate Date Ranges
        if ($(this).val() != '' && dates.not(this).val != '') {
            if ($(this).hasClass("FromCal")) {
                if (new Date(testDate) > new Date(otherDate)) {
                    addError($(this));
                    $('.flightDateError').text('* Start date must be earlier than end date.');
                    isValid = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else{
                if (new Date(testDate) < new Date(otherDate)) {
                    addError($(this));
                    $('.flightDateError').text('* End date must be later than start date.');
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The main Issue is this part, I believe

```
 // Validate Date Ranges
            if ($(this).val() != '' && dates.not(this).val != '') {
                if ($(this).hasClass("FromCal")) {
                    if (new Date(testDate) > new Date(otherDate)) {
                        addError($(this));
                        $('.flightDateError').text('* Start date must be earlier than end date.');
                        isValid = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (new Date(testDate) < new Date(otherDate)) {
                        addError($(this));
                        $('.flightDateError').text('* End date must be later than start date.');
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

testDate is the start date
otherDate is the end date

Here is the C# where the two input boxes are

```
    <div id="campaign_start" style="display: inline-block">
                    <label class="date_range_label">from:</label>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="FromCalTbx" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="FromCal editable float_left required" />
                  </div>
                  <div id="campaign_end" style="display: inline-block">
                    <label class="date_range_label">to:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ToCalTbx" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="float_left optional"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @James: You should try associating you Programmers.SE account, so that you can regain ownership of this question.  If you're not registered on Programmers.SE, consider registering.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing both dates with the same method, but need different outcomes. Looks like the 'FromCal' class is pretty important here; can you show some HTML to make it more clear what it does and how the date picker works? (Sorry about the reply, my reputation prevents me from commenting, I think)