# JQuery Validation dates

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get my form to validate...so basically its working, but a little bit too well, I have two text boxes, one is a start date, the other an end date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy

if the start date is greater than the end date...there is an error 
if the end date is less than the start date...there is an error 
if the start date is less than today's date...there is an error

The only thing is when I correct the error, the error warning is still there...here is my code:

```
// Validate Date Ranges
            if ($(this).val() != '' && dates.not(this).val != '') {
                if ($(this).hasClass("FromCal")) {
                    if (new Date(testDate) > new Date(otherDate)) {
                        addError($(this));
                        $('.flightDateError').text('* Start date must be earlier than end date.');
                        isValid = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (new Date(testDate) < new Date(otherDate)) {
                        addError($(this));
                        $('.flightDateError').text('* End date must be later than start date.');
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and here are the two text boxes:

```
<div id="campaign_start" style="display: inline-block">
                <label class="date_range_label">from:</label>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="FromCalTbx" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="FromCal editable float_left required" />
              </div>
              <div id="campaign_end" style="display: inline-block">
                <label class="date_range_label">to:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ToCalTbx" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="float_left optional"/>
</div>
```

PS - 
testDate is the start Date
otherDate is the end Date

Comment: This would be better suited for StackOverflow

Comment: @Kevin D - Agreed.  James, please update the HTML portion to show client output, the server side code does not matter.  Where does C# come into play here?

Comment: there is no HTML its was writen in C#...do u want to see the full jquery function? is that what you mean?

Comment: James, the `<asp` tags are going to be translated to HTML on the client side.  The top portion of code looks like jQuery/JavaScript.  Are you doing client side validation (JS) or server side validation (C#)?

Comment: its a .ascx file is where the text boxes are

Comment: client side validation.....jquery

Comment: I will try not too sir...dont know how it got migrated to StackOverflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245065/jquery-validation)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, fixing the dates doesn't make the error message go away?

If that's so, try adding an else to your two if statements and it clear the error text field.

So:

```
else { 
    $('.flightDateError').text(''); 
}
```

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to do...I will try your answer right now...which if statment are you talking about? The hasClass one, the testDate > otherDate or testDate < otherDate?

Comment: Thanks Tyanna...it worked!...I did try this before but for only one of the if statements...thanks !